# #define ISR(x) #pragma isr=x

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have problems with this attempt at a macro:

```
#define ISR(x) #pragma isr=x
```

doesn't compile because it's trying to replace `#pragma` with a nonexistent parameter. Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I'd like to get `ISR(VEC1)` expanded as `#pragma isr=VEC1`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. It is possible to define a macro that expands into a pragma directive using the `_Pragma` unary operator.

From 6.10.9 of the C99 Standard:

> A unary operator of the form: `_Pragma (` *string-literal* `)` is processed as follows: The string literal is *destringized* by deleting the `L` prefix, if present, deleting the leading and trailing double-quotes, replacing each escape sequence `\"` by a double-quote, and replacing each escape sequence `\\` by a single backslash. The resulting sequence of characters is processed through translation phase 3 to produce preprocessing tokens that are executed as if they were the *pp-tokens* in a pragma directive. The original four preprocessing tokens in the unary operator expression are removed.

An example from the Standard is:

```
#define LISTING(x) PRAGMA(listing on #x)
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
LISTING ( ..\listing.dir )
```

which is equivalent to:

```
#pragma listing on "..\listing.dir"
```

Therefore, this is what you are looking for:

```
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
#define ISR(x) PRAGMA(isr=x)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will not work as in the code

```
#define ISR(x) #pragma isr=x
```

The "#" in a macro definition is Stringification operator. That is if # is preceded to an argument it will stringify it else # operator will be ignored.  So in summary to answer your question you can't do this.

If your compiler implements  C99 you can use _Pragma instead like this

```
#define ISR(X) _Pragma(isr=x)
```

More reference on _Pragma [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v111v131/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp111.linux.doc/language_ref/c99preprocessor.html)

Comment: There is a slight problem with your definition of `ISR`. The argument to `_Pragma` needs to be a single string literal.

Comment: My bad yes you are right it needs to be stringify before passing to _Pragma